# Batch processing each page of .pdf in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, batch-processing

I have a 100-something paged .pdf file, and I want to apply the same operation to each page:

1- select blacks with a certain fuzziness

2- erase background

3- copy the layer with blacks, blur, merge and then apply unsharp mask

4- fill bg with white

At the end of this I want to save the pages in a single .pdf file with the same order. Is this doable without converting the .pdf file into 100 image files and batch processing them?

Comment: To clarify, are you looking to do this all within Acrobat?

Comment: @Ovaryraptor I was going to do it in Photoshop, but I'm open to using Acrobat if the operations I want to apply to the pages are doable there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option would be to create an action to do the required editing and then split it up into individual pages.

Then you can use `File -> Automate -> Batch` to run the action and set up where to copy the edited files.

[image]