# Batch processing images to be proportional

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, batch-processing, crop

I have a series of small images, all on white backgrounds.

Some of them are square proportioned, others are rectangular proportioned; either vertically or horizontally. I'm looking to make all all of the images square, the size doesn't matter but the proportion does.

Is there a quick way to batch process all images so that it turns rectangular images into squared images while keeping them centered and also ignoring images that are already square?

I'd try a macro or script, but I don't know how to code something like: "make the image and bigger at its biggest side".

I'm working with Photoshop but I can upload the images to any online tool if needed.

Comment: Is there any reason why you couldn't separate the images first?

If you can do that you can just use the built-in Batch-Processing feature in Photoshop.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor I could but will take some time, supposing I could quickly sort squared from non-squared images, how do I use the processor to make a rectangular image squared?

Comment: Please see my other answer. https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/97205/43400

Comment: If one of requirements is "while keeping them centered" then I'm afraid automation won't work.  If the images were all in the same position it would work. Photoshop knows nothing about objects in a photo - there is no way for the software to automatically find where an object is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I won't go into detail about the batch process. It should be enough to know that you can run a script through the `File > Automate > Batch...` by first making a Photoshop Action, where you open a script file: `File > Scripts > Browse...`. Obviously you can also do more things within that same Action.

I'm not exactly confident I understand what you want, so I'm posting 2 scripts. Make a new `.jsx` file where you paste one of these scripts and use that in the action.

These both work with portrait and landscape images.

#### Image to square - Shrink script.jsx:

[image]

```
var rUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

var doc = app.activeDocument;
var docWidth = doc.width;
var docHeight = doc.height;
var newSize = docWidth > docHeight ? docHeight : docWidth;

app.activeDocument.resizeCanvas( newSize, newSize, AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER );

app.preferences.rulerUnits = rUnits;
```

---

#### Image to square - Grow script.jsx:

[image]

The extended background color comes from the background color set in the toolbar.

```
var rUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

var doc = app.activeDocument;
var docWidth = doc.width;
var docHeight = doc.height;
var newSize = docWidth > docHeight ? docWidth : docHeight;

app.activeDocument.resizeCanvas( newSize, newSize, AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER );

app.preferences.rulerUnits = rUnits;
```

Comment: amazing, right what I was looking for (2nd script) with the only difference that our images are always on white background, so If I set white in the toolbar I can run the batch with no issue right?

Comment: @S.Redrum,  yes. You can test the script on a single image first.

Comment: it works like a charm, only stop I encountered was on one image where it asked to confirm the quality ratio for saving it. Can I add something to tell the script to also save the image with no prompt?

Comment: @S.Redrum uh oh... Should be possible, but I don't have an answer to that right now. I should've tested this on multiple images, but didn't. Gonna check that out....

Comment: @S.Redrum, oh wait. Now that I really read what you said, I realize that it wasn't the script that caused this dialog. The thing I don't quite get is why. Here's an example of how these things can happen. It's typically inconsistencies, like for example: If you make an action where you `close a document` and this document you use to make the action has been saved, it will close without ever showing you a dialog. Then... one of the images you run the action on has not been saved after changes. So when your Action tries to close it, it asks if you want to save the document or not,

Comment: because the dialog behavior was not saved in the Action. You can make sure it is, by recording the Action using a document that has not been saved. That way it works for both saved and unsaved documents. The reason why I'm not sure what is going on with your Action specifically, is that I can't think of a situation where it would suddenly decide that the quality setting is not saved in the Action... I feel like it should always be. The saving of the image can indeed be added to the script, in fact the whole process could be handled with a script, but it's fairly cumbersome.

Comment: it asks to confirm JPEG quality for every file :'( I have read similar posts where a tick in "disable save as" worked, I'm gonna try that.

Comment: How are you saving the images? Are you using the `Destination: Save and Close` in the Batch dialog? I'm pretty sure that is your issue. I would say that more often than not, you'll want to record your own Save action and Close action in the PS Action (and set Destination as: none in the Batch dialog).

Comment: Yes I added the save as in the macro :) this resolved, thank you!

Comment: @S.Redrum that's great.

Comment: I need to create an Action with your second script but I don't know how to do it from the code you posted. Can you give direction to get it. This is the first time I create an action from a code. Thanks.

Comment: @JPashs, you need to copy and paste the code to a text file and save it as plain text with the filename:`Image to square - Grow script.jsx`. The name itself isn't important, but the extension "jsx" is. Then you should start recording the Action and open the script from `File > Scripts > Browse...`.